# How do I create Upload/Download only permission in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

How do I create Upload only permission in SharePoint Online?

I have a sever external facing sites for our clients and I want users to be able to login see the site, go to the document library and add files or download/open files. However I dont want them to be able to "edit" the home page and it seems every way ive tried this that's available. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom permission level by “Copy Permission level” from **READ** permission via *Settings > Site permissions > Advanced permissions settings > Permission Levels* and give **Add Items** permission to the new permission level.

Or, if you don’t want the users from accessing or editing any other locations in this site, create unique permission on this library and give then View Only access to the site.

References:

[Permission levels.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/how-to-create-and-edit-permission-levels)

[SharePoint site permissions.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/customize-sharepoint-site-permissions)

Comment: Thank you! This worked.

Comment: @DickyDal Would you please give it a vote or accept it as answer if you find the reply helpful? It will help others in this forum to find answers quickly as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I encountered with the solution from Chelsea_MSFT is that you can edit the source document if you have the "Open in the App" feature making the edit in SharePoint possible

Answer (score -1):

If you can download then upload, you can essentially edit and delete by making modifications to the file before upload.  You need one library where they can read only and another where they can upload.  Then someone (you?) can verify that the document uploaded does not overwrite an existing file.